# Отображение элементов в нокаут

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Можно ли средствами библиотеки Knockout js отобразить массив элементов таким образом, чтобы каждый последующий элемент появлялся на странице спустя определенное количество секунд?

Comment: И за чем тут библиотека или именно данную библиотеку надо использовать?

Comment: @Air - да именно эта библиотека используется, поэтому необходимо пользоваться функционалом данной библиотеки.

Comment: Сорри, не знаю с ней не знаком.....